# Making a thumbnail if there exist a link with. jpg or .png extension in Wordpress

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, links, thumbnails

I have changed my question. I was wrong. Check it out I'd say.

Is this possible to make a thumbnail if a link contains a `.jpg` (or `.png`) extension?

I want to make it a thumbnail automatically if there is a link like http://externalsiteorso.com/blablabla.jpg --> make this a thumbnail.

If it's possible, how can I do this and solve the problem?

I have found this, but it's not for `Wordpress`, I guess.

```
$extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Read source image
if ($extension == ('jpg' || 'jpeg')) {
    $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename); 
    return '1';
} else if ($extension == 'png') {
    $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
    return '2';
} else {
    return 'error';
}
```

Comment: how do you call this function in your template?

Comment: Like this `<?php get_first_image(); ?>`

Comment: That function returns an image URL when I test it but that alone is not going to create a thumbnail.

Comment: Well, can someone help me making it a thumbnail? Where do I start, what should I do?

Comment: Whad to you need exactly, can you explain more?

Comment: @Greeso Well, if there is an `img` tag in a post or a comment, I want to make that a thumbnail, instead of a link to the image. Is that possible?

Comment: It is possible, but requires quet a customization. What you need to do is use xpath to read your post, then extract the images you like and attach them to the post. Then you clean up your post removing the images. I am doing something along those lines myself, but it did require a lot of code, and it varies per situation. So this is just an idea.

Comment: I have changed my question. See post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check out:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_sideload_image

2. I found that WP function to be somewhat limited to I wrote my own wrapper class/method. If you want to do the same you're going to need PHP's copy() function

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

as well as WP's wp_insert_attachment()

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment

Unfortunately, I haven't pushed my code to GitHub just yet, so for now you'll have to put something together yourself.

Comment: I am not that good in coding, but will look at it at least. Thanks.